# Strong params with array in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following JSON:

```
{"id":"6","restaurant_menus":[{"restaurant_menu_items":[{"image":null,"title":"1","description":"2","cost":"3"}],"title":"Title"}],"format":"json","action":"update","controller":"restaurants","restaurant":{"id":6}}
```

I want Rails to pass id, restaurant_menus with nested restaurant_menu_items, and I tried to do it with it:

```
params.require(:restaurant).permit(:id, { restaurant_menus: [:id, :title, { restaurant_menu_items: [:id, :image, :title, :description, :cost] } ] })
```

But this code passes only the first 'id'. How can I do it right?

Comment: What is your `params` value? You should confirm whether Rails can receive input parameters or not. Please put `logger.debug(params)` before `params.require(:restaurant).permit(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this.

```
params.require(:restaurant).permit(:id,
                                   restaurant_menus: [
                                       :id,
                                       :title,
                                       restaurant_menu_items: [
                                           :id,
                                           :image,
                                           :title,
                                           :description,
                                           :cost
                                       ]] )
```